# Meshing an inclusion in an inclusion

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method, mesh, acegen

I do have FEM mesh related question. I am trying to mesh some inclusion from a png file using ToElementMesh. Thats working quite nicely even for more complex structures.

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
img = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "2_round_inclusions.png"];
Show[img, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[img, "RegionHoles" -> None, 
  "RegionMarker" -> {{{150, 250}, 1, 100}, {{400, 125}, 1, 
     100}, {{1, 1}, 1, 1000}}]
```

[image]

But now I want to have another inclusion within both inclusions and that seem not to work out straight forward.
I tried to do it the same way as before:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
img = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "grain_in_grain.png"];
Show[img, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[img, "RegionHoles" -> None, 
   "RegionMarker" -> {{{250, 200}, 1, 1000}, {{100, 200}, 1, 
      1000}, {{20, 200}, 1, 1000}}];
```

,but no mesh is generated. Instead Mathematica crashes. Does anyone have an idea how to go on from that point?

Thanks in advances

Max

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you share the images without the Axis?

Comment: Sure! Is it okay like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Updated answer

This update describes the workflow to create an inclusion within an inclusion mesh based on an image in more detail.

In this case, [`ImageForestingComponents`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageForestingComponents.html) appears to do a good job separating the regions. We can use [`DominantColors`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DominantColors.html) to separate by color and view as a dataset.

```
pts = {{250, 200}, {100, 200}, {20, 200}};
ifc = ImageForestingComponents[img, pts, 3] // Colorize;
ds = DominantColors[ifc, 
  3, {"NearestHTMLColor", "Coverage", "CoverageImage"}, "Dataset"]
```

[image: Dominant color dataset]

Ultimately, we want an image with the middle region stripped out. This way, we will be able to create an element mesh that we can extract a boundary mesh so that we can apply region markers. The negative of the coverage image of row 2 meets the requirement.

```
Print["Image of the middle region removed"]
domImg = ds[2, -1] // ColorNegate
```

[image: Domain image]

Now, we will create a mesh based on the above image, extract a boundary mesh, and build a mesh with the appropriate region markers.

```
Print["Mesh the domain image"]
(m = ToElementMesh[domImg])["Wireframe"]
Print["Extract boundary mesh"]
(bm = ToBoundaryMesh[m])["Wireframe"]
Print["Final mesh with region markers"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[bm, "RegionHoles" -> None, 
   "RegionMarker" -> {{#1, 1, 1000}, {#2, 2, 1000}, {#3, 3, 1000}} & @@
     pts];
mesh["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElementStyle" -> {FaceForm[Green], FaceForm[Red], 
    FaceForm[LightBlue]}]]
```

[image: Updated meshes]

## Original answer

Something like this works, but you may want to do something to smooth the outer ellipse because it is over-refined.

```
cc = ClusteringComponents[img, 3];
bm = ToBoundaryMesh@
   ToElementMesh[Colorize[cc /. {3 -> 0}] // Binarize];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bm, "RegionHoles" -> None, 
   "RegionMarker" -> {{{250, 200}, 1, 1000}, {{100, 200}, 2, 
      1000}, {{20, 200}, 3, 1000}}];
mesh["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElementStyle" -> {FaceForm[Green], FaceForm[Red], 
    FaceForm[LightBlue]}]]
```

[image]

Here is a version that applies a [`GaussianFilter`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GaussianFilter.html) to the image.

```
bm = ToBoundaryMesh@
   ToElementMesh[
    GaussianFilter[Colorize[cc /. {3 -> 0}], 10] // Binarize];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bm, "RegionHoles" -> None, 
   "RegionMarker" -> {{{250, 200}, 1, 1000}, {{100, 200}, 2, 
      1000}, {{20, 200}, 3, 1000}}];
mesh["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElementStyle" -> {FaceForm[Green], FaceForm[Red], 
    FaceForm[LightBlue]}]]
```

[image: Filtered]

The results are much nicer.

Comment: This are pretty nice examples and they are working quite well! Great!